# HorizontalAlign in gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GrdiView` on an asp.net page. I am setting the datasource to a `DataTable`. I need to set `HorizontalAlign` to left if the value in the cell is of type string, else if it is a decimal, I want it to be aligned to the right. Please let me know how to implement this. The code for the `GridView` is as follows:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gridViewReport" runat="server" Height="1px"       OnRowDataBound="UsersGVRowDataBound" GridLines="both" Style="z-index: 100; 
        left: 2px; position: absolute; top: 1px; " Width="939px" CellPadding="4"   ForeColor="#333333" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridViewReport_Sorting" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridViewReport_SelectedIndexChanged1">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#EFECE5" />            
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C0F6C0" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CDE472"  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="DarkGreen" HorizontalAlign ="Left"  Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Overline="False"/>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#EAEAAE" />            
    </asp:GridView>
```

Also, the code for setting the `DataSource` is as follows:

```
gridViewReport.DataSource = _reportTable;
gridViewReport.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if each of your columns contain data of the same type you would already know which columns carry decimal and which don't

so considering your `DataTable` has **two columns** and first column is carrying string and second column is carrying decimal you can do

```
    protected void gridViewReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;       
        }
    }
```

else if your column carries text which can either be a decimal or string you can do this (say the second column in `DataTable` has text **which can potentially contain decimal format** as well)

```
    protected void gridViewReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal val;
            if(decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[1].Text, out val))
                e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            else
                e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My gridview is carrying data of different types. Each time a new report is getting generated. So I will have to find out the datatype dynamically and set the alignment accordingly. Thats the problem

Comment: If you are autogenerating the columns, I am afraid, you will need to to dynamically do it of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I looped through the cells and did it

Answer (score 1):

You can handle gridViewReport_ItemCreated() event and set up alignment of various columns as

`e.Item.Cells[<zero-based-index-of-column>].Style["text-align"] = "right";`

Comment: I want to align only the decimal type cells to the right, and the other strings to the left. How do I find out which one is decimal and which is string type while populating gridview dynamically?

Comment: as you know datatype of each column, you need to calculate index of column containing decimal type data (Beware of hidden columns if any)

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it gridViewReport_ondatabound events.

```
protected void gridViewReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal cellValue = 0.0m;
            DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

            if (dr[urs_cell_index] != null)
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(dr[urs_cell_index].ToString(), out cellValue))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[urs_cell_index].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[urs_cell_index].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```